# clickhouse using JDBC engine error "No suitable driver found"

Tags: java, jdbc, clickhouse

I have created my clickhouse table using JDBC engine. But when id run a query, it calls

```
DB::Exception: Received error from remote server:

/identifier_quote?connection_string=jdbc%3Amysql%3A%2F%2F10.117.130.95%3A3306%2F%3Fuser%3Droot%26password%3D**. 

HTTP status code: 500 Server Error, body: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://10.117.130.95:3306/?user=root&password=** (version 20.5.2.7 (official build))
```

this is my engine set:

```
engine = JDBC('jdbc:mysql://10.117.130.95:3306/?user=root&password=**','pma','t_dept');
```

Comment: just look at doc: "To implement the JDBC connection, ClickHouse uses the separate program [clickhouse-jdbc-bridge](https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-jdbc-bridge) that should run as a daemon". It needed to install and configure [clickhouse-jdbc-bridge](https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-jdbc-bridge) on CH node.

Answer (score 1):

There needs to be a mysql jdbc driver jar file present in your classpath.

MySql refers to it as a 'Mysql Connector' and google pops up a version 8.0.21 here : https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/ however as with any link / versioned file, you may need to perform your own search / adjust for the mysql database that you're using.  (Generally, but not always being slightly behind on the driver side vs database version is ok).